# Make custom groups based on ID who have specific values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For example i have next table

| user_id | event | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | name_1 | null |
| 1111111 | name_2 | null |
| 2222222 | name_1 | null |
| 2222222 | name_2 | null |
| 2222222 | name_3 | yes |
| 3333333 | name_1 | null |
| 3333333 | name_2 | null |
| 3333333 | name_3 | no |

and i need to select ids and new column based on events and actions

- 1 group - id has events 1 and 2
- 2 group - id has all 3 events and action of name_3 is 'no'
- 3 group - id has all 3 events and action of name_3 is 'yes'

So desired output:

| user_id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | group_1 |
| 2222222 | group_3 |
| 3333333 | group_2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a conditional aggregation approach we can try:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT event) = 3 AND
              MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'name_3' THEN action END) = 'no' THEN 2
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT event) = 3 AND
              MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'name_3' THEN action END) = 'yes' THEN 3
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT event) = 2 AND
              COUNT(CASE WHEN event = 'name_1' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
              COUNT(CASE WHEN event = 'name_2' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 END AS "group"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Note that this approach is efficient as it requires making only a single pass over the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `UNION ALL` to combine 3 queries :

```
 select user_id, max('group_1') as 'group'
 from mytable
 group by user_id
 having count(distinct case when event in ('name_1', 'name_2') then event end ) = 2 
       and count(distinct event) = 2
union all
 select user_id, max('group_2') as 'group'
 from mytable
 group by user_id
 having count(distinct case when event in ('name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3') then event end ) = 3 
       and count(case when event = 'name_3' and action = 'no' then event end ) = 1
union all
 select user_id, max('group_3') as 'group'
 from mytable
 group by user_id
 having count(distinct case when event in ('name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3') then event end ) = 3 
       and count(case when event = 'name_3' and action = 'yes' then event end ) = 1
```

Tested on mysql, check [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2jsdXsK5)

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL) assuming only those three cases/groups can have a place

```
select user_id, if(
    logical_and(event in ('name_1', 'name_2')), 
    'group_1', if(max(action) = 'yes', 'group_2', 'group_3')
  ) as `group`
from your_table
group by user_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]